# Custom Post Type Metadata Not Saving

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, save-post

I created a client profile custom post type and have started creating the meta boxes and such for users to enter in information. While all of that seems to be working fine, when I go to save the custom post, nothing gets sent to the database. Here are my functions

**Meta Box**

```
function add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'client-info',
        __( 'Client Information', 'textdomain' ),
        'meta_box_clientinfo_callback',
        'clientprofile',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxes' );
```

**Client Info Meta Box Callback**

```
function meta_box_clientinfo_callback( $post )  {
    global $my_post_meta;
    $my_post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'my-nonce' );
?>

    <p>Please enter in the information on the client whom you wish to feature in a case story.</p>
    <p>
        <label for="client-name"><?php _e( 'Client Name', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="client-name" id="client-name" value="<?php field_value( 'client-name' ); ?>" size="25" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="client-age"><?php _e( 'Client Age', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="client-age" id="client-age" value="<?php field_value( 'client-age' ); ?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="client-gender"><?php _e( 'Client Gender', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <select id="client-gender" name="client-gender">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>

<?php
}
```

**Save Post**

```
function save_meta( $post_id ) {

    // Verify Nonce
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['my-nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my-nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['client-name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_client_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST{'client-name'} ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post'. 'save_meta', 10, 2 );
```

**Field_Value Function**

```
function field_value( $field_id ) {

    global $post_meta;

    if ( isset ( $post_meta[$field_id] ) ) {
        echo $post_meta[$field_id][0];
    }
}
```

What am I missing something here? I looked at several examples online to get the code I have now but when I look in PHPMyAdmin at the `wp_postmeta` table for the Post ID, I only see keys for `_edit_last` and `_edit_lock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue is your `save_post` action isn't firing because:

```
add_action( 'save_post'. 'save_meta', 10, 2 );
```

should be

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta', 10, 2 );
```

You also have inconsistency between `client-name` and `_client_name`, but without seeing the `field_value` function, I'm not sure if that's a problem or not.

I would also use something more unique than `save_meta` and `add_meta_boxes` for function names, potential for collision with some other code is high.

Comment: I removed the name spacing to make for simpler reading and shorter lines of code. I did change the `.` to a `,`, but am still seeing just the two keys in `wp_postmeta` from before, even on a new post.

Comment: A copy/paste of your code works for me, as far as saving is concerned. You've still got some naming issues with your `field_value` function, so you won't see the saved values in your form field, but it does end up in the database.

Comment: Can you copy what you had into pastebin or something so I can compare? It's still not working for me.

Comment: [Here it is](https://pastebin.com/xfwP3PFE). I changed the post type to `post` in `add_meta_box`, and added a `print_r($my_post_meta)` in `meta_box_clientinfo_callback` to show all the saved meta data.

Comment: Still unable to get it to work with the custom post type. I even tried using the `'save_post_mycpt'` hook for `add_action()` per the `save_post_{$post->post_type}` hook that was added in 3.7

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the issue is. Maybe try with the `post` type like I was to verify that that the issue isn't related to the CPT?

Comment: I put some `error_log()` statements in the `'save_post'` action function. It looks like it wasn't getting passed the conditionals. The nonce is failing and when I took that out it still wasn't reaching down so I rewrote the capability checks and it fired off finally and is storing in the database.